# Is this statement true, false, or not a mathematical statement?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$ \forall x \in  X: \left \{x \right \} \in  2^X $

I'm just really unsure about this one, so please help me out. Thanks!

Comment: @amWhy: If you edit in the $\in$, don't forget to remove the $\epsilon$! :-)

Comment: @Asaf Did I leave it? Oh my! (Thanks for fixing my "fix".) I stopped getting the preview window when I edit anything! I get it before posting a new answer, but I don't get previews of any edit. Any tips?

Comment: @amWhy: Compile $\LaTeX$ in your head, and be more careful to review. That's usually what I do (when working on .tex files, since I still get a live preview here).

Comment: @AsafKaragila When you compile $\LaTeX$ in your head, do you also sometimes say to yourself that some labels may have changed and you should run your head again?

Comment: @Hagen: No, I always run the compiler twice. I do forget to run BibTeX often, though. So I get these question marks sometimes... ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, this is a mathematical statement. In the context of set theory everything is a set, so we can always ask whether one thing is an element of another; but even if not we often identify between the functions from $X$ into $\{0,1\}$ and the power set of $X$. The former is often written as $2^X$.

But this is a contextual problem. Sometimes we want to really separate between the set of functions $2^X$ and the power set of $X$, $\mathcal P(X)$. So now we have a problem.

- If we separate the two, then $\{x\}\in\mathcal P(X)$ because it is a subset of $X$, but it is not true that $\{x\}\in 2^X$, since it is not a function whose domain is $X$ and its range is $\{0,1\}$ (well, not usually, since under reasonable assumptions if $\operatorname{dom}(f)=X$ then $f\notin X$).

  And therefore in this case, $\{x\}\notin 2^X$.
- If we do identify the two, then indeed $\{x\}$ is a subset of $X$ therefore it is an element of $\mathcal P(X)$, which we have identified with $2^X$, so $\{x\}\in 2^X$ is a true statement.

Answer (score 3):

Well $2^X$ is the power set of $X$, i.e. it is the set of all subsets of $X$, thus indeed $\{x\}\in 2^X,\forall x\in X$.

Comment: It is *often* identified with the power set of $X$. But formally speaking, it is not the power set of $X$.

Answer (score 3):

This is a true mathematical statement. It says that for any element $x$ of a set $X$, the set $\{ x\}$ is one among the collection of all subsets of $X$.

Comment: See my comment to ellya, and my answer.